# Angular 9 - Cypress vs Selenium(BrowserStack)

Tags: angular, selenium, cypress, e2e-testing, browserstack

I have an Angular 9 Nrwl project and I want to add some automated tests. I am confused a bit between Selenium(Browserstack) and Cypress that comes built in with the project. What's the better choice for Angular kind of projects and why.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress has recently added support to Fire fox and MS Edge. If your application doesn't need to support legacy browsers go for it. Check its browser support.

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/310

The last release from Protractor was at least an year back, the other hand Angular team has taken the ownership of Protractor
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5209#issuecomment-523182031
But at this moment its still unclear how well Angular team would support it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Cypress if the project is built in. But at the same time it has some trade-offs / restrictions. It only supports latest browsers and they are still in beta for Firefox and edge chromium version. Selenium has more options and features as compared to cypress such as multi-tabs support, muti domain support in single test and it can be written in any language but cypress can only be written in JS. Also, cypress does not support testing on real devices, at most you can resize the desktop browser window to make it look like mobile and test on it.